# Three-way graph (variable, mean, sd) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, facet, standard-deviation

I think I have an error in my logic while reproducing a graph I found in this pdf [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/bigvis.pdf).

It should be fairly easy to do, but I have issues to plot a variable with its mean and standard deviation each in their own graph together, as can be seen in the example graph below. Did they do it with `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()`?

How can I plot an arbitrary variable in that way? **In particular, I would not know how to plot the mean and sd over distance (or time).**

Example graph:
[image]

Comment: You need to calculate these 3 functions over Distance, melt the data over Distance and use `facet_grid` over Distance. There is nothing special about this graph

Comment: Thank you, David, for your answer. Can you please help me out how to calculate the mean over distance on an arbitrary data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my approach to the solution outlined by @DavidArenburg (though I simplified the data a little, using simple cumulative statistics and a plain index):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(TTR)
v <- rnorm(1000)
df <- data.frame(index = 1:1000, 
                 variable = v, 
                 mean = runMean(v, n=1, cumulative=TRUE), 
                 sd = runSD(v, n=1, cumulative=TRUE))
dd <- gather(df, facet, value, -index)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = index, y = value)) + 
  geom_path() +
  facet_grid(facet ~ .)
```

[image]

Bonus: illustration that sample mean and sd are unbiased (0 and 1, respectively).

Comment: Awesome! That answer rocks!